# Json пример обыкновенного массива

Tags: json

Как в JSON задать правильный формат простого массива только лишь с ключом? Делаю вот так, ругается:

```
{
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Данные в формате ***JSON*** ([RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627)) представляют собой:

- Объекты `{ ... }` или
- Массивы `[ ... ]` или
- Значения одного из типов:

  - строки в двойных кавычках,
  - число,
  - логическое значение `true`/`false`,
  - `null`.

Объект в **JSON** имеет такой вид:

```
{"ключ":значение, "ключ": значение}
```

А вот так выглядит массив:

```
["значение", "значение"]
```

В вашем случае корректный **JSON** массив будет:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Выдержка из RFC:

> A JSON text is a serialized object or array.
>
> ```
>   JSON-text = object / array
> ```

Comment: Да, вы правы, я не знал об этом. Удалю пожалуй свой ответ.

Comment: Как адаптировать это решение под мой вопрос?

Comment: @asd массив является корректным json: [1, 2, 3, 4]